# Outlook items.restrict gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, exchange-server

I am trying to get the mails from outlook by programmatically which received time is greater than a certain time like:

```
oItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > " + receivedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

"receivedTime" is the time which will be passed to the function. But it gives error. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing single quotes around the value, it should be

```
oItems.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" + receivedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'");
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210275(v=office.11).aspx